# make: *** [Makefile:30: modules] Error 2 while installing seeed-linux-usbdisp

Tags: pi-4, kernel, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, makefile

So I was trying to use WIO Terminal as a small display for my raspberry pi 4. And I was following the official setup [from here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYqr1auC8wA). And during the making of the display driver I'm encountering an error.

```
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build KCPPFLAGS="-I/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src -I/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/../common" M=/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.21-v8+'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.o
In file included from ./include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/inc/common.h:19,
                 from /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:15:
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c: In function ‘_display_defio_handler’:
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:40: error: ‘struct fb_deferred_io’ has no member named ‘pagelist’; did you mean ‘pagereflist’?
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:18:26: note: in definition of macro ‘container_of’
   18 |  void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);     \
      |                          ^~~
./include/linux/list.h:531:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_entry’
  531 |  list_entry((ptr)->next, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:674:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_first_entry’
  674 |  for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member); \
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_for_each_entry’
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/container_of.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/inc/common.h:19,
                 from /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:15:
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:40: error: ‘struct fb_deferred_io’ has no member named ‘pagelist’; did you mean ‘pagereflist’?
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
./include/linux/build_bug.h:78:56: note: in definition of macro ‘__static_assert’
   78 | #define __static_assert(expr, msg, ...) _Static_assert(expr, msg)
      |                                                        ^~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:19:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘static_assert’
   19 |  static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) || \
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:19:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__same_type’
   19 |  static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) || \
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:520:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
  520 |  container_of(ptr, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:531:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_entry’
  531 |  list_entry((ptr)->next, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:674:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_first_entry’
  674 |  for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member); \
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_for_each_entry’
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:40: error: ‘struct fb_deferred_io’ has no member named ‘pagelist’; did you mean ‘pagereflist’?
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
./include/linux/build_bug.h:78:56: note: in definition of macro ‘__static_assert’
   78 | #define __static_assert(expr, msg, ...) _Static_assert(expr, msg)
      |                                                        ^~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:19:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘static_assert’
   19 |  static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) || \
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:20:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘__same_type’
   20 |         __same_type(*(ptr), void),   \
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:520:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
  520 |  container_of(ptr, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:531:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_entry’
  531 |  list_entry((ptr)->next, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:674:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_first_entry’
  674 |  for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member); \
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_for_each_entry’
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
././include/linux/compiler_types.h:298:27: error: expression in static assertion is not an integer
  298 | #define __same_type(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/build_bug.h:78:56: note: in definition of macro ‘__static_assert’
   78 | #define __static_assert(expr, msg, ...) _Static_assert(expr, msg)
      |                                                        ^~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:19:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘static_assert’
   19 |  static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) || \
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/container_of.h:19:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘__same_type’
   19 |  static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) || \
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:520:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
  520 |  container_of(ptr, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:531:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_entry’
  531 |  list_entry((ptr)->next, type, member)
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:674:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_first_entry’
  674 |  for (pos = list_first_entry(head, typeof(*pos), member); \
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_for_each_entry’
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/inc/common.h:19,
                 from /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:15:
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:40: error: ‘struct fb_deferred_io’ has no member named ‘pagelist’; did you mean ‘pagereflist’?
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
./include/linux/list.h:665:20: note: in definition of macro ‘list_entry_is_head’
  665 |  (&pos->member == (head))
      |                    ^~~~
/home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.c:265:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘list_for_each_entry’
  265 |     list_for_each_entry(cur, &fbdefio->pagelist, lru) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:250: /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver/src/fbhandlers.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2012: /home/pi/seeed-linux-usbdisp/drivers/linux-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.21-v8+'
make: *** [Makefile:30: modules] Error 2
```

This is the error I'm getting. This is official github repo of the [display driver](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/seeed-linux-usbdisp/tree/master/drivers/linux-driver).

Comment: Have you asked on the github?

Comment: Not yet. I'm gonna ask it there.